# Non-linear differential equation example

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm dealing with the following differential equation

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{(y-x)(a-by)}{(1-\frac{b}{a}x)(a-2by+bx)}$ with $x,y \in [0, \frac{a}{b}]$

Can anyone help me with the non trivial solution?

Thanks.

Comment: How can we show you your mistake if you don't show us your working?

Comment: I didn't mean to check my working, I was wondering whether the solution is correct or not.

Comment: @PK.K : See my answer. For information : A solution, but not all solutions, is $$y=\frac{(a+b)x+a}{a+2b}$$

Comment: @PK.K . HINT : another much simpler solution is obvious. Don't you see it ?

Comment: Yes the (1,0) solution is obvious but it is a corner solution and not desirable for the application I'm looking for.

Comment: @JJacquelin Thanks for your help.

Comment: Set $u=a-bx$, $v=a-by$ then $$\frac{dv}{du}=\frac{a(u-v)v}{bu(2v-u)}$$ is a homogeneous ODE. Now set $v=uw$ and continue as usual.

Answer (score 0):

To your question : "whether my solution is correct or not ?" the answer is obviously NO.

Putting your solution $$y(x)= \frac{a}{2b} +\frac{x}{2}$$
into
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{(y-x)(a-by)}{(1-\frac{b}{a}x)(a-2by+bx)}$$
shows 
$$(a-2by+bx)=0$$
at denominator.